# Need Assistance with Calculating the Area of a Square when given the diagonal.

Tags: geometry, area

It's been several years since I've done this stuff---I'm trying to brush up for a Praxis exam in a few weeks.
I've come across a problem I'm having a lot of trouble with.

I'm given a square.

The diagonal of the square is 9√2 .
It wants me to find the area of the square using the length of the diagonal.

I assume I will use the Pythagorean theorem here.

So... I have to right triangles within this square, both with a hypotenuse of 9√2.
So, I have a^2 +b^2=c^2.
Since this is a square, I can assume that a=b.
So, I can just figure for a.
a^2+a^2=162 (9√2*9√2)
2a^2=162
a^2=81
a=9
since a=b,b=9

Therefore, the area of the square will be 81.

Am I completely off on this?

Comment: That looks correct!

Comment: perfectly valid reasoning. you may see how to generalize your argument. if the diagonal of a square is $d$, then the area must be $\frac{d^2}2$. what about the volume of a cube?

Comment: You.are right.   For fun let's do it more geometrically. Let the diagonal be $d$.  Cut the square into $2$  parts along the diagonal. You now have $2$ triangles. Make a photocopy of  each of these. You can probably see how to rearrange our $4$ triangles to make a square with side $d$. So $4$ triangles altogether have area $d^2$. Thus the $2$ triangles that make up the original square have combined area $\frac{d^2}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a really easy way:

Any square is a rhombus. So, you can use it's formula for square area calculation and it's just $\frac{d^2}{2}$

Regards